# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a varchar(1000) column declared as field that contains all numbers, as shown below.
And I want to execute the following script.  I  need this to work please

```
Declare @PostalCode varchar(1000)=0
    set @PostalCode ='7005036,7004168,7002314,7001188,6998955'

Select hl.* From CountryLocation cl
INNER JOIN refPostalCodes pc ON pc.PostalCode = hl.PostalCode
where pc.Postalcode in (@PostalCode) and pc.notDeleted = 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299(SQL.80).aspx):

```
Declare @PostalCode varchar(1000)=0
    set @PostalCode ='7005036,7004168,7002314,7001188,6998955'

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)  //didn't count the chars...

select @sql = N'Select hl.* From CountryLocation cl
INNER JOIN refPostalCodes pc ON pc.PostalCode = hl.PostalCode
where pc.Postalcode in (' + @PostalCode + ') and pc.notDeleted = 1'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

You need to be **very careful** about SQL injection when coding this way.

Comment: Thanks Austin for the quick answer.  
The postalcodes are fetched from a listbox (multiselect true).

Comment: Hi Austin, Sorry i forgot to give vote.  When i come back and I see your answer wasn't there in my list.