# Stored procedure conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my stored procedure, I am facing the following problem - how can i fix this?

```
CREATE PROC RupeshTest(@QueID int, @Answer varchar(250)) as
BEGIN
   DECLARE @STR varchar(4000) 

   SELECT @STR = COALESCE(@str + ';','') + AnswerText     
   FROM SurveyQuestionAnswerTypes 
   WHERE AnswerType = (SELECT AnswerType 
                       FROM SurveyQuestions 
                       WHERE QuestionID = CAST(@QueId AS VARCHAR(4))) 
                         AND AnswerValue IN (REPLACE(@Answer,'^',','))
END
```

When I run it

```
RupeshTest 25, '2^3^5^7^8'
```

I get following error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RupeshTest, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2,3,5,7,8' to data type int.

Although I understand the problem, but unable to fix it, could some body tell me how can I fix it.

Comment: i am facing problem in replace function ..

Comment: Formatting works just fine :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654393/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-data-type-int)

Comment: You're attempting magical programming - *why* do you expect the SQL language to peer inside a single string parameter, and decide that it should split it around the commas and turn it into *multiple* parameters, when no other programming language that I know of would do this?

Comment: the solution is to make/create the SQL command as string and run it.

Comment: there is reason to replace it because from front end it goes like this '2^3^5^7^8'  so i need to change it

Comment: AnswerValue is int type..what table regarding you want to know?

Comment: Ok lets put it the other way what int value are you expecting in the transform of `'2,3,5,7,8'` ?

Comment: yes, that is coming out but it should be like 2,3,5,7,8

Comment: Important point: anything you do here is going to involve building a custom TSQL string at runtime; you **must** ensure the string is something reasonable; trusting that from an external source could lead  to data damage (see my comment on avani's answer)

Answer (score 2):

This wont work, since the final Query being formed is :

```
SELECT @STR = COALESCE(@str + ';','') + AnswerText     
   FROM SurveyQuestionAnswerTypes 
   WHERE AnswerType = (SELECT AnswerType 
                       FROM SurveyQuestions 
                       WHERE QuestionID = CAST(@QueId AS VARCHAR(4))) 
                         AND AnswerValue IN ('2,3,5,7,8')
```

Where as you want something like this:

```
SELECT @STR = COALESCE(@str + ';','') + AnswerText     
   FROM SurveyQuestionAnswerTypes 
   WHERE AnswerType = (SELECT AnswerType 
                       FROM SurveyQuestions 
                       WHERE QuestionID = CAST(@QueId AS VARCHAR(4))) 
                         AND AnswerValue IN (2,3,5,7,8)
```

I would advice you to make a UDF String_To_Table, pass the string to that UDF and use for the IN clause.

String_To_Table UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[String_To_Table]
                    (@string      VARCHAR(4000),
                     @delimiter CHAR(1) = ';')
         RETURNS @tbl TABLE (ord INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                             token     VARCHAR(500)) AS

   BEGIN
      DECLARE @pos      int,
              @textpos  int,
              @chunklen smallint,
              @tmpstr   varchar(4000),
              @leftover varchar(4000),
              @tmpval   varchar(4000)

      SET @textpos = 1
      SET @leftover = ''
      WHILE @textpos <= datalength(@string)
      BEGIN
         SET @chunklen = 4000 - datalength(@leftover)
         SET @tmpstr = @leftover + substring(@string, @textpos, @chunklen)
         SET @textpos = @textpos + @chunklen

         SET @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @tmpstr)

         WHILE @pos > 0
         BEGIN
            SET @tmpval = ltrim(rtrim(left(@tmpstr, @pos - 1)))
            INSERT @tbl (token) VALUES(@tmpval)
            SET @tmpstr = substring(@tmpstr, @pos + 1, len(@tmpstr))
            SET @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @tmpstr)
         END

         SET @leftover = @tmpstr
      END

    IF ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)) <> ''
        INSERT @tbl(token) VALUES (ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)))


 RETURN
   END
```

Then you can change your SP as below:

```
CREATE PROC RupeshTest(@QueID int, @Answer varchar(250)) as
BEGIN
   DECLARE @STR varchar(4000) 

   SELECT @STR = COALESCE(@str + ';','') + AnswerText     
   FROM SurveyQuestionAnswerTypes 
   WHERE AnswerType = (SELECT AnswerType 
                       FROM SurveyQuestions 
                       WHERE QuestionID = CAST(@QueId AS VARCHAR(4))) 
                         AND AnswerValue IN (SELECT Token FROM dbo.String_To_Table(@Answer,'^'))
END
```

Comment: One of these days, someone at MS is going to explain to me why SQL Server ***still*** doesn't have an inbuilt "split" method.

Comment: Important security concern: the OP should probably be pretty sure that the input string isn't actually `1^2^3) DROP TABLE Students --^4`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing here is the part  `AnswerValue IN (2,3,5,7,8)` and how to make it valid SQL because the values are a list of Integers and you have them as strings. One trick for me is to make all the SQL command a string and Execute it:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS varchar(4000)

SET SQLQuery = 
'SELECT AnswerText '
+ ' FROM SurveyQuestionAnswerTypes '
+ ' WHERE AnswerType = (SELECT AnswerType '
                   + ' FROM SurveyQuestions '
                   + ' WHERE QuestionID = ' + CAST(@QueId AS VARCHAR(4))) 
                    + ' AND AnswerValue IN (' + (REPLACE(@Answer,'^',',')) + ')'


EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

by the way, there is no reason to send the numbers with the ^ and then change it.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the last condition with

```
AND CHARINDEX(CONCAT("^", CAST(AnswerValue AS CHAR), "^"), CONCAT("^", @Answer, "^"))
```

It doesn't seem totally right, but it might do the trick.

**edited**

Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured. Sorry for that, I'll fix it

Comment: LOCATE(MySQL) or CHARINDEX(MSSQL) wont be a good solution. The SP will fail when the input is like RupeshTest 25, '112^233^225895^9967^1238' the result will match for 1,2,3,8,9,11,12,23,38 and so on combinations

Comment: You're right. Maybe it should be CHARINDEX('^' + CAST(AnswerValue AS CHAR) + '^', '^' + @Answer + '^')

Comment: @avanigadhai I can't comment your answer but shouldn't you SELECT _token_ instead of _ID_ in the subquery where you call String_To_Table? Im not very familiar with mssql so I may be missing something there.