# SQL stored procedure sent data for "IN" condition

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a stored procedure and it has where condition using 'IN' key word. So I want to send more than one value to stored procedure .

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxx]
   @COM_KEY varchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT     
       UserName, UserId
    FROM 
       company        
    WHERE      
       (COM_KEY IN (@COM_KEY))
END
```

So I pass the value in here

```
string companyID = "";

for (int i = 0; i < lbCompanies.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        companyID += Convert.ToInt32(lbCompanies.Items[i].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        companyID += "," + Convert.ToInt32(lbCompanies.Items[i].Value);
    }
}

DataSet ApproveList = DataRepository.TUsersProvider.xxx(companyID);
```

but there is an error

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3087,4058' to data type int*

How can I solve it?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? At first sight seems that theproblem is that you are passing a varchar to the in clause where the query expects a list of int.

Comment: For confirmation, that error show up when the `IN` statement?

Comment: The format for `IN` is `IN ('something', 'something else')` not `IN ('something, something else')` more less like that, see my answer for it.

Comment: Check my answer, it will works for you.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass a comma-delimited string into `@COM_KEY`. You should pass an array.

One way to accomplish this task would be using [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Have a look at this article, under `Solution #3`: [TSQL: Passing array/list/set to stored procedure (MS SQL Server)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113458/TSQL-Passing-array-list-set-to-stored-procedure-MS).

In essence, you treat your series of `int`s as a table you apply `JOIN`  upon, and not query it via `WHERE ... IN ()` phrase.

Comment: Don't like it. If you have a look at the article I quoted, they mention your solution and then proceed to much more efficient method.

Comment: They are listing a number of solutions and they also quoted as for simple cases this solution is enough.And for this particular this will works as expected.Thanks for pointing to that any ways:)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `UserDefinedFunction` which parses the string and puts each integer extracted into a table to solve this issue

```
CREATE Function fnSplitter (@IDs Varchar(100) )  
Returns @Tbl_IDs Table  (ID Int)  As  

Begin 
 -- Append comma
 Set @IDs =  @IDs + ',' 
 -- Indexes to keep the position of searching
 Declare @Pos1 Int
 Declare @pos2 Int

 -- Start from first character 
 Set @Pos1=1
 Set @Pos2=1

 While @Pos1<Len(@IDs)
 Begin
  Set @Pos1 = CharIndex(',',@IDs,@Pos1)
  Insert @Tbl_IDs Select  Cast(Substring(@IDs,@Pos2,@Pos1-@Pos2) As Int)
  -- Go to next non comma character
  Set @Pos2=@Pos1+1
  -- Search from the next charcater
  Set @Pos1 = @Pos1+1
 End 
 Return
End
```

Now alter your stored procedure like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxx]
@COM_KEY varchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT UserName, UserId
 From company        
 WHERE COM_KEY IN (Select ID From dbo.fnSplitter(@COM_KEY))
END
```

*Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6083/Passing-comma-delimited-parameter-to-stored-proced) for detailed Implemetation*

Comment: This works, we use it in a large production environment, but not out of desire. Table valued functions as mentioned in the answer Ofer posted are a better option if the are available to you. If they are off the table, go with this solution. Please don't resort to dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial solution to your problem is to vale SQL string(for dynamic Query) and then execute the statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxx]
   @COM_KEY varchar(max) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

SET @SQL=N'    SELECT     
       UserName, UserId
    FROM 
       company        
    WHERE      
       (COM_KEY IN ('+@COM_KEY+'))'
EXCE @SQL
END
```

Solution mentioned by @ssilas777 is the sophisticated version for the same.

Also note that using `IN` is not always advisable. I have run into

> query time out errors

when `IN` has lot of IDs

Comment: Please don't use this solution. Dynamic SQL is almost never the proper solution.

Comment: @ChrisPorter I know, I too mentioned in my reply that its the most trivial solution, based on the version of SQL server. Else you can refer to this post as well [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511029/stored-procedure-conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-data-typ/10511247#10511247]

Answer (score -3):

Change your code from:

```
if (i == 0)
{
  companyID += Convert.ToInt32(lbCompanies.Items[i].Value);
}
else
{
  companyID += "," + Convert.ToInt32(lbCompanies.Items[i].Value);
}
```

to:

```
if (i == 0)
{
  companyID +="'" + Convert.ToInt32(lbCompanies.Items[i].Value) + "'";
}
else
{
  companyID += ",'" + Convert.ToInt32(lbCompanies.Items[i].Value) + "'";
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the values in single quotes won't solve the data type issue that he is having. You cannot execute a IN clause against a varchar parameter, regardless of the values being escaped by single quotes.